# Can a # symbol be stored in url and included in `REQUEST_URI`?

Tags: php

using

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ;?>
```

when the url is: `www.site.com/a/b/c/#d`

does not show the `#d`, but instead shows `/a/b/c`

Is this possible to include, or is it hidden for a reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

whatever behind the `#` is client-side only. Server will not receive that.